# Which wavelength of light can reflect easiest on any material?

Tags: reflection, wavelength

What I know is, when wave has long wavelength it tend to penetrate matter. While a short wavelength tend to be absorbed

So what is the medium value of wavelength has most probability to reflect? And what situation is causing it? Is it because the average size of atom? Or it is a constant value across universe?

Comment: It's wrong. Microwaves (with comparably long waves) in a microwave oven can't exit the oven, while you can still see visible light (much shorter waves) coming through the holes when the oven is working. I.e. visible light penetrates the perforated metal screen in the door, while longer wavelengths of microwave radiation don't.

Comment: See [Why glass is transparent?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/why-glass-is-transparent). Although this is specifically about glass it applies to any material.

Comment: @JohnRennie Sorry but I already know all about those and I know that glass are transparent because light has less frequency energy than the band gap of glass, that's why I ask this question that what is the range of frequency that cannot pass many kind of material but not be absorbed (so it would reflect)

Comment: @Ruslan Also it another problem that some material has so low band gap and it absorb microwave but there are holes to let photon with shorter wavelength pass those holes, if there aren't hole on that material it would not let those light pass through right? Soit out of my question